# Condition of Convergence for the following Integral, evaluated using Gamma Function.

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Question:
**Evaluate in terms of the Gamma function the integral** $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^x}  dx$$
And state the condition on $k$ such that the integral converges.

**Attempt**

Let $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k^x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x\ln(k)}\cdot x^k dx$$
So $k>0$ and $k$ can not be negative.

Let $y = x\cdot\ln(k)$.

After simplification and using the gamma function:

$$I = \frac{1}{(\ln k)^{(k+1)}}\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y}\cdot y^k dy$$
$$ I = \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{(\ln k)^{(k+1)}}$$

Now how to find the condition for the integral to converge, without graphing the function?

I thought it is $k>0$, but graphing the function shows that it diverges except when $k>1$

Comment: If $0<k<1$, then $1/k^x=(1/k)^x$ grows exponentially. Thus, the integral cannot converge. The case $k=1$ is also obvious. Your change of variables is incorrect if $0<k\le 1$ since then $\ln(k)\le 0$, which changes the range of integration (or for $k=1$ is useless).

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks @Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^x}dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x\ln k}\cdot x^k dx$

$\pi(k) = \int_0^\infty x^ke^{-x}dx$

$I=\frac{1}{(\ln k)^{k+1}}\int_0^\infty (x \cdot \ln k)^k\cdot e^{-x\ln k}\cdot \ln k \cdot dx $

$u=x \ln k. du =dx \ln k$

$I=\frac{1}{(\ln k)^{k+1}}\int_0^\infty u^ke^{-u} du=\frac{\pi(k)}{(\ln k )^{k+1}}$

$\Gamma{(k+1)}=\pi(k)$

---

To prove divergence, you can use a comparison test.

$I=\int_0^\infty e^{-x\ln k}\cdot x^k dx$

$k$ must be greater than zero because of the domain of natural log. If $k\ge 1$, we have the case addressed above.

Consider $0<k<1. \implies\ln k <0$.

$I=\int_0^1 e^{-x\ln k}\cdot x^k dx+\int_1^\infty e^{-x\ln k}\cdot x^k dx>\int_0^1 e^{-x\ln k}\cdot x^k dx+\int_1^\infty e^{-x\ln k}dx=\int_0^1 e^{-x\ln k}\cdot x^k dx+\infty$

The first part of the integral is bounded, the second part, on the interval from 1 to $\infty$ diverges. Since I is greater than the unbounded part, it must diverge.